# Ubuntu not connecting to wifi sometimes

Tags: wireless, networking, 13.10

So I am using Ubuntu 13.10 on my Lenovo U310 laptop and I am having some problems with wifi on it.

Wifi usually works fine, it's just that the model has a poor placement of the chip or something so I need to be really near the router. But sometimes when I wake my laptop from sleep mode, it will not connect to any wifi for some reason.

I have tried to disable Wifi and Networking when that happens, but it fixes nothing. Only way to get to connect again is to restart the computer.
Why does this happen and how can I fix it? Restarting computer every time for it seems a bit extreme I think.

Comment: Any help with this ?

Comment: I have the same experience with an ubuntu 18.04 installation